# Не запускаеться xterm через QtCreator

Tags: linux, qtcreator

Не запускается xTerm.Хоть и пишу простой вывод какого либо сообщения через `cout`. Хоть и xTerm присутствует.Галочка запустить в терминале в настройках проекта тоже есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте в настройках проекта установлена ли галочка у свойства "Запускать в терминале".

Comment: Да, есть галочка

Comment: В таком случае при вызове вашего приложения через QtCreator терминал должен запускаться в отдельном окне. Попробуйте пересобрать вашу программу, также можете попробовать запустить её руками из терминала.

Comment: Ну раньше так и было(запускалось в отдельном окне)

Comment: и еще к тому же через терминал запускаеться

Comment: тоже поменял стандартный терминал на `/usr/bi/terminator -x`, но приложения не запускаются. Получилось как-то победить?

Comment: Да, я точно не помню, но там нужно было в настройках qt изменить что-то